# strange string on xml (&#8230;)

Tags: xml, rss, cdata

I see that some `rss` on `xml` have strange strings.

For example, `...` is `&#8230;`.

What is this? And why? Its about `CDATA`?

On my web application (C#), reading rss, I usually do `myString.Replace("&#8230;", "...")` : not sure if it's the best strategy

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are [numeric character references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference).

> A numeric character reference (NCR) is a common markup construct used in SGML and other SGML-related markup languages such as HTML and XML. It consists of a short sequence of characters that, in turn, represent a single character from the Universal Character Set (UCS) of Unicode.

In this case, the numeric character reference for the [ellipsis character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) - `…`.

Comment: What other special (yet common) characters are used in this manner?

Answer (score 2):

From this [reference page](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) it's *horizontal ellipsis*.